# Spring 4.x compatible with Java 16

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, java-16

I am currently migrating my application from Java 8 to Java 16 and currently, I am running Spring 4.x. Would this Spring 4.x be compatible with Java 16 or I need to upgrade the Spring jar to the latest version?

Comment: facing issue with spring jpa data


 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.<init>(java.lang.Class,int)
  at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3517)
  at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2691)
  at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:486)
  ... 65 more

Answer (score 2):

**JDK Version Range**

- Spring Framework 5.3.x: JDK 8-19 (expected)
- Spring Framework 5.2.x: JDK 8-15
- Spring Framework 5.1.x: JDK 8-12
- Spring Framework 5.0.x: JDK 8-10
- Spring Framework 4.3.x: JDK 6-8

For more info please visit here [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions)